# Imagem desaparece ao fazer um flip no sprite

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou desenvolvendo em HTML5 mas estou tendo o seguinte problema uma `sprite` faz os movimentos para a direita, mas quando tento dar o *flip* nela para fazer a imagem ser exibida virada para esquerda utilizando `ctx.scale(-1, 1);`
A imagem simplesmente não aparece, segue o código que fica atualizando toda hora.

OEle está entrando no `if` do `walk_left` normalmente.
O código funciona, eu não peguei ele todo por isso não está com as tags do JavaScript.
A única coisa que não está funcionando é o andar para esquerda, quando eu ando para esquerda a imagem simplesmente some.

```
function redraw()
{
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var w = img.naturalWidth / 8;
    //  var largura_frame = (w);
    //  var altura_frame = ;
    // posx = 100;
    // var posy = 100;
    var rect_img_height = (img.naturalHeight / 8) - 3;
    var rect_img_width = (w) - 2;
    var rect_height = (img.naturalHeight / 8);
    var rect_width = img.naturalWidth / 8;
    var rect_posx = frame * (img.naturalWidth / 8) + 1;
    //      var rect_posy = 120  ;
    var rect_posy = null;

    ctx.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0, bgImg.naturalWidth, bgImg.naturalHeight, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (imageReady)
    {
        if (walk_right == 1 && walk_left == 0)
        {
            rect_posy = 120;
            ctx.drawImage(img, rect_posx, rect_posy, rect_img_width, rect_img_height, posx, posy, rect_width, rect_height);
        }
        else if (walk_left == 1 && walk_right == 0)
        {
            rect_posy = 120;
            //posx = posx * -2
            ctx.save(); // Save the current state
            ctx.scale(-1, 1);
            //posy = 100; posx = 100;
            ctx.drawImage(img, rect_posx, rect_posy, rect_img_width, rect_img_height, posx, posy, rect_width, rect_height);
            ctx.restore();
        }
        else
        {
            rect_posy = 257;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 162, rect_posy, rect_img_width, rect_img_height, posx, posy, rect_width, rect_height);
        }

        ctx.font = "30px Arial";
        ctx.fillText('pos x: ' + posx, 150, 130);
        ctx.fillText('img heigth ' + bgImg.height, 150, 150);

        ctx.fillText('canvas width ' + canvas.width, 150, 180);
        ctx.fillText('canvas heigth ' + canvas.height, 150, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Fernando

Answer (score 1):

Bem `scale` negativo funciona, só que ele inverte totalmente as coordenadas,
sendo que se você seta `scale x` como negativo você deve mudar as coordenadas do `objeto` referente a `x` para negativos.

No seu caso você deve editar essas posições referentes a `x` para negativas:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, rect_posx, rect_posy, rect_img_width, rect_img_height, posx, posy, rect_width, rect_height);
```

Segue [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3Bf/3/)

Comment: Eu tenho uma imagem virada para a direita -> eu quero que ela vire para esquerda <- sem rotacionar pois ficaria de cabeça para baixo. mesmo assim obrigado por tentar ajudar.

Comment: @LucasDuca, entendi, pode criar um [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), para pode entender melhor?

Comment: Resolvido obrigado!!!

Comment: @LucasDuca se ficou completamente resolvido, marque como resolvido por favor.